# Combo box don't show items added

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box in a form

Then in form_load fill the combo:

```
Private Sub FrmEstadisticasVentas_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    cbTipoProductos.ReCreateReparented = True 

    cbTipoProductos.AddItem("PACKS")
    cbTipoProductos.AddItem("MANTENIMIENTOS")
    cbTipoProductos.AddItem("PRODUCTOS")
    cbTipoProductos.AddItem("PACKS y MANTES")

End Sub
```

Then when run the project, my Combo Box is clear, there are any Item

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and VB.NET

What is the problem??

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly is the type of `cbTipoProductos`?

Comment: is a Xtreme ComboBox (Codejock)

Comment: The ActiveX (COM) version?

Comment: Regardless, that's a third-party control library.  If you are having trouble with their products, I would recommend that you post a question on [their support site](http://forum.codejock.com/).  It's not strictly off-topic here, but you'll probably get more expert advice there, since it's apparently not popular enough of a library to have warranted it's own tag on StackOverflow yet.

Comment: I wish the OP had stated it was a third party control in the original message before I posted my answer. Explains why they didn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know how your example ran without error. Anyway, it should be:

```
    cbTipoProductos.Items.Add("PACKS")
    cbTipoProductos.Items.Add("MANTENIMIENTOS")
    cbTipoProductos.Items.Add("PRODUCTOS")
    cbTipoProductos.Items.Add("PACKS y MANTES")
```

Comment: Ignore the above answer. It wasn't stated in the original question that a third-party control was being used.